# QVariant::isNull() and custom type

Tags: c++, qt

Can I somehow use `QVariant::isNull()` with a custom `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` type?

For example, if I define such a wrapper class for an integer (why should I, but this should be a minimal example). Defining a `bool isNull() const` member function doesn't help:

```
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

class Integer {
    bool null;
    int x;
public:
    Integer() : null(true), x(0) {}
    Integer(int x) : null(false), x(x) {}
    int value() const {
        return x;
    }
    bool isNull() const {
        return null;
    }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Integer)

int main()
{
    Integer x(42);
    Integer y(0);
    Integer z;

    qDebug() << x.isNull() << QVariant::fromValue(x).isNull();
    qDebug() << y.isNull() << QVariant::fromValue(y).isNull();
    qDebug() << z.isNull() << QVariant::fromValue(z).isNull(); // Not as expected!
}
```

Output:

```
false false 
false false 
true false     // Not as expected!
```

Comment: This question has no meaning. Try asking more detailed questions in some context. Preferably in a sample piece of code

Comment: @cppguy Oh yes it does. There is `QVariant::isNull()` which checks if the *value* of the variant "is null": The documentation says nothing about how this is defined. For example, `QString::isNull()` is used if the type is `QString`. So the question is: What is used when the type is a user-defined one?

Comment: Did you try defining a `bool isNull() const` member function? The Qt source code seems to try to find one and uses it if it is defined (using template specialization).

Comment: @leemes "Returns true if this is a NULL variant, false otherwise." meaning, the variant has no type assigned to it yet

Comment: @cppguy No, see the example with the null QString in the documentation. `QVariant(QString())` has a type (!= Invalid) and isNull() returns true. Also, they write: "QVariant also supports the notion of null values, where you can have a defined type with no value set."

Comment: I added an example. I hope this illustrates it.

Comment: Despite this problem, note that operations performed directly on a QVariant with custom types aren't implemented as expected. For example the comparison operators perform a *pointer comparison*, even if your type overloads all the necessary operators!

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately you can't. The `QVariant::isNull` code is the following:

```
static bool isNull(const QVariant::Private *d)
{
    switch(d->type) {
    case QVariant::String:
        return v_cast<QString>(d)->isNull();
    case QVariant::Char:
        return v_cast<QChar>(d)->isNull();
    case QVariant::Date:
        return v_cast<QDate>(d)->isNull();
    case QVariant::Time:
        return v_cast<QTime>(d)->isNull();
    ...
    }
    return d->is_null;
}
```

As you can see it explicitely uses the `isNull()` function of some common variable types and by default it returns the `d->is_null` value.

The `d->is_null` is a class member of the D pointer of the `QVariant` class which is initialized to `true` but every time you assign a value to the `QVariant` it becomes `false`:

```
inline void qVariantSetValue(QVariant &v, const T &t)
{
    ...
    d.is_null = false;
    ...
}
```

So for custom types it will always return `false`.

One possibility (**which I do not recommend**) would be to subclass `QVariant` and reimplement the `isNull` function. In this function you could check if the type is custom and in this case you can return the return value of the `isNull` function of your custom class, otherwise you should return the return value of the `QVariant::isNull` function.

```
bool MyQVariant::isNull() const
{
    if (QString(typeName()) == "MyCustomClass")
       return value<MyCustomClass>().isNull();
    return QVariant::isNull();   
}
```

**EDIT**

Your example code using the subclassed QVariant:

```
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

class Integer {
    bool null;
    int x;
public:
    Integer() : null(true), x(0) {}
    Integer(int x) : null(false), x(x) {}
    int value() const {
        return x;
    }
    bool isNull() const {
        return null;
    }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Integer)

class MyQVariant : public QVariant
{
public:
    MyQVariant(QVariant v) :
      QVariant(v) {}
    bool isNull() const
    {
        if (QString(typeName()) == "Integer")
            return value<Integer>().isNull();
        return QVariant::isNull();   
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Integer x(42);
    Integer y(0);
    Integer z;

    qRegisterMetaType<Integer>("Integer");

    MyQVariant v1(QVariant::fromValue(x));
    MyQVariant v2(QVariant::fromValue(y));
    MyQVariant v3(QVariant::fromValue(z));

    qDebug() << x.isNull() << v1.isNull();
    qDebug() << y.isNull() << v2.isNull();
    qDebug() << z.isNull() << v3.isNull();
}
```

Output:

```
false false 
false false 
true true
```